# Add Entry from Listbox to Most Recent Textbox By Double Clicking in VBA Userform

Tags: excel, vba, listbox

I am trying to find a way to have a user doubleclick an entry within a listbox, and paste it into the textbox they most recently had focus on. So, with a list box like

```
With ListBox1
    .AddItem "<PARENT> Customer's PARENT Company "
    .AddItem "<SALESEXEC> The sales executive responsible for the account"
    .AddItem "<FIRSTNAME> Customer's First Name"
End With
```

I would like to be able to past these values into a textbox, but because the form has multiple textboxes, I want it to be the last one they have focus on. I was thinking of doing something like following. The issue is I can't seem to get `GotFocus` event  to do anything. It does work with `Enter` event, but that only works once.

```
Public hasFoc As String
Private Sub TextBox4_GotFocus()
    Debug.Print ("TextBox4 Clicked")
    hasFoc = "TextBox4"
End Sub

Private Sub ListBox1_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)

'Get index of clicked element, and paste the "<>" 
'value into the most recently used textbox

End Sub
```

Edit: I haven't handled classes before in VBA, but my class module looks like this:

```
Option Explicit

Public WithEvents txtBox As MSForms.TextBox

'/ To Mimic Enter event .
Private Sub txtBox_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
    '/ Assign to global variable
   Set g_ActiveTextBox = txtBox
End Sub

'/ To Mimic Enter event .
Private Sub txtBox_MouseDown(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
     '/ Assign to global variable
    Set g_ActiveTextBox = txtBox
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom event handler class, mimic the Enter event by capturing MouseDown and KeyDown events. When the UserForm loads, hook all the Textboxes to custom event. Whenever a TextBox is accessed by User, store that in a global variable (in  a standard module). On ListBox DblClick, Just set the selected item text to the TextBox. Simple!!! :)

See the full VBA code below:

VBA Class (EventH) for the custom event handling.

```
Option Explicit

Public WithEvents txtBox As MSForms.TextBox

'/ To Mimic Enter event .
Private Sub txtBox_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
    '/ Assign to global variable
   Set g_ActiveTextBox = txtBox
End Sub

'/ To Mimic Enter event .
Private Sub txtBox_MouseDown(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
     '/ Assign to global variable
    Set g_ActiveTextBox = txtBox
End Sub
```

VBA UserForm, with TextBoxes and ListBox

```
Option Explicit

Dim oCol                    As New Collection '/ Holds the custom events and keeps them alive

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    '/ Start EventHandler hooking.
    Call addEventhandlers
End Sub

Sub addEventhandlers()
    '/ Adds custom event handler to all TextBoxes of this UserForm
    Dim oEventH     As EventH
    Dim ctrl        As Control

    For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
        If TypeName(ctrl) = "TextBox" Then
            Set oEventH = New EventH
            Set oEventH.txtBox = ctrl
            oCol.Add oEventH
        End If
    Next

End Sub

Private Sub ListBox1_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    '/ Copy Text from ListBox to Last active TextBox
    Dim i As Long

    If Not g_ActiveTextBox Is Nothing Then
       For i = 0 To Me.ListBox1.ListCount - 1
          If Me.ListBox1.Selected(i) Then
              g_ActiveTextBox = Me.ListBox1.List(i)
          End If
      Next i
    End If
End Sub
```

A standard module to declare the global variable.

Option Explicit

```
Global g_ActiveTextBox      As MSForms.TextBox '/ Global variable to hold the last active textbox
                                               '/  Don't act smart and move it to UserForm as public.
                                               '/ That will fail.
```

Comment: I really appreciate the answer, the only issue is I get an error "User-defined type not defined" for `Dim oEventH As EventH`. Do you know why this would be?

Comment: You need to rename your event handler class `EventH`

Comment: OK, I thought that may be it, but I've never handled classes before in VBA. Is there an initialization function I need to include with the class? Or, is there a simple way of renaming it?

Comment: I tried View -> Properties Window -> Name -> EventH, but I get an error "can't perform the requested operation". Edit: "Events" works. Didn't realize that was the name. Thank you very much for your help @cyboashu.